# how to move the content of a uiimage in a certain direction

Tags: ios, uiimage, cgcontext

I used UIBezierPath to crop part of a image with a size 1920*1080, discarding  1/3 of it(from left). i want the left 2/3 move left to left aligned to the left aboard of the image , i tried:

```
-(UIImage*)leftAlignmentLeftTrapezoided:(UIImage*) image{
    // extract each half as a CGImage
    CGImageRef imageRight = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage],CGRectMake(self.size.width/3, 0, self.size.width,self.size.height));
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(self.size.width/3,self.size.height),NO, 0);
    CGContextRef con = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextDrawImage(con,CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.width*2/3.0,self.size.height), imageRight);
    UIImage* im = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return im;
    /*

     */
};
```

according to http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html, but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center it :

let's make an example with hyphen

6 ------

6 - (1/3) * 6 = 6 - 2 = 4

4 ----

let's try to align them :

first: : : : : : :        **------**

second: : : :      x----x

**With words** if you cut a part (let's call it x) of a segment and still want it to be in the center of some axe you have to cut x/2 of the segment from both part of you're segment ,

In your case Just move it from 1/6 of the width (1920) in the left if you want it to be centered

If you want it to be on the left:

in the first place put your image with 1/3 in left of the position you want it to be .

Hope it helped
(sorry for bad English)

Comment: thank you very much. i have find a method http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.sg/2010/11/drawing-part-of-uiimage.html .  the two line of code  is very important:      // Take care of Y-axis inversion problem by translating the context on the y axis
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, drawRect.origin.y + fromRect.size.height);  
        
        // Scaling -1.0 on y-axis to flip
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);